# Estimated deaths if Covid control is based on herd immunity

Tags: covid-19, united-states

Rachael Maddow suggested on her 9/16/20 show that reliance on herd immunity (naturally acquired immunity) to control the continued spread of COVID-19 could result in the death of 2 to 6 million Americans.
Is this plausible? And if not why not?

(Factors she applied: Herd immunity threshold of approximately 65%, Population of 320 million, mortality rate between 1 and 3%)